# How do I write the reference mark symbol ※ in TeX?

Tags: symbols, typewriter

Consider the [reference mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_mark) symbol, ※, also pictured below:

[image: Reference mark]

How can I write this symbol in TeX?

Comment: This is available in [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](//texdoc.net/pkg/comprehensive) (Table 46: Miscellaneous `textcomp` Symbols).

Comment: What's the usage of this symbol?

Comment: @User It is one of the symbols used to show contradiction.

Comment: I use it in the margin of my papers instead of "TODO" or "FIXME". But that's really up to you :-) That said, I simply use the Unicode character U+203B REFERENCE MARK directly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `\textreferencemark`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\textreferencemark

\end{document}
```

The results with `xelatex` and `pdflatex` are a little different, see the following screenshots:

| `xelatex` | `pdflatex` |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 6):

I used `\bigtimes` from Unicode math. Define `\timesdots` like this:

```
\def\timesdots{\vbox{\baselineskip=0pt \lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen 
   \halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      $\cdot\kern-.44em\bigtimes\kern-.44em\cdot$\cr\noalign{\kern.2em}
      .\cr\noalign{\kern-.8em}.\cr\noalign{\kern.6em}}}%
}
```

If you want to use Unicode character U+203B (Reference Mark), then you can use `\char"203B` in Unicode TeX engine or directly use it ※ in your TeX source file.

Answer (score 6):

Picture mode!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\newcommand{\blob}{%
  \raisebox{0.02em}{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.107em}%
    \linethickness{0.4\unitlength}%
    \begin{picture}(8,6)
    \roundcap
    \Line(1,0)(7,6)
    \Line(1,6)(7,0)
    \put(4,0.5){\makebox(0,0){.}}
    \put(6.5,3){\makebox(0,0){.}}
    \put(4,5.5){\makebox(0,0){.}}
    \put(1.5,3){\makebox(0,0){.}}%
    \end{picture}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

A\blob B

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
$ \divideontimes$
```

[image]

Not exactly, but similar :-))

Comment: Almost – but not entirely – quite unlike it ;-)